# jQuery toggle backgroundPosition on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This changes background position on hover, I want to return position to 0 0 on mouse out. How do I do it?

```
$("#love").hover(function () {
    document.getElementById('love').style.backgroundPosition= "0 -19px";
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, you should use CSS rather than JavaScript because it will be faster:

```
<style type="text/css">
#love {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#love:hover {
    background-position: 0 -19px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#love").hover(function () {
document.getElementById('love').style.backgroundPosition= "0 -19px";
},function () {
 document.getElementById('love').style.backgroundPosition= "0 0";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use power of jQuery

```
$("#love").hover(function () {
    $(this).css('background-position', '0 -19px');
}, function() { 
    $(this).css('background-position', '0 0');
});
```

or it can be done just in css using `:hover`

Comment: You might want to double check your code... you set to `0 -19px` on both conditions.